# Scope error in lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Tags: laravel, scope

I'm getting following error in my Laravel project:

> The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed. Check the
>   \"scope1,scope2\" scope

I'm using multiple scope in my route.

If I use single scope it's working. If I use multiple scope it's throwing above error.

This is my code,

```
$api->group(['prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 
    'App\Http\Controllers\User', 'middleware' => [ 
    'oauth:scope1+scope2'],'before' => 'oauth'], function ($api) {
    //routes
}
```

Thank you